# AWS SES - Is it possible to configure 2 "mail_from_domain" addresses under the one "domain_identity"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

AWS SES - Is it possible to configure 2 "mail_from_domain" addresses under the one "domain_identity"?

For example:

domain identity = website.com

mail_from_domain = admin.website.com

mail_from_domain = support.website.com

or can wildcard be used:

mail_from_domain = *.website.com

thanks

K

Need solution to above

Comment: Why do you need such a solution? When should the given Mail from domain be used instead of the other one?

Comment: The product support has 2 emails they want to send from in different scenarios. If SES doesnt support more that one mail_from, is setting up 2 seperate SES in different regions using the same domain the only option?

Comment: There is one important thing: normal email address FROM is completely different than mail_from_domain. If your product support would like to use the different address FROM, they use. If you have a domain abc.com verified, then you can use any subdomains from this domain to it. What is the reason that you would like to also use SPF checks for your specific reasons?

Comment: The AWS has no way of determining when to apply one of the different MAIL_FROM domains. The best scenario for that, is that I would verify 2 different domains and then create a separate MAIL_FROM domains and use them with it.

Comment: There is one important thing: normal email address FROM is completely different than mail_from_domain. If your product support would like to use the different address FROM, they use. If you have a domain abc.com verified, then you can use any subdomains from this domain to it. What is the reason that you would like to also use SPF checks for your specific reasons?


^
I think this is what I needed, so I will not bother adding mail_from set up, once subdomain is verified then I should be able to use any prefix as an email from that domain. Will try this.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question once and for all:

Whenever you have the domain `domain.com` verified, you can send mails from all of the subdomains of that domain, for instance both: `A.domain.com` and `B.domain.com` will be valid.